# Como cambiar el nombre a una columna de un jTable?

Tags: java

De que manera se podria realizar esto en tiempo de ejecucion, una vez ya se haya anteriormente puesto los nombres?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si al momento de ejecutarse el programa y luego quieres cambiar las columnas tendrias que implementar algun metodo haciendo lo siguiente:

```
    public void changeColumnName(int __COLUMN__, String __NAME__){
        JTableHeader head = Tabla.getTableHeader();
        TableColumnModel tcm = head.getColumnModel();
        TableColumn tabCM = tcm.getColumn(__COLUMN__);
        tabCM.setHeaderValue(__NAME__);
        Tabla.repaint();
    }
```

Ya el resto es llamar la funcion y pasarle los argumentos

Comment: Perfecto, gracias.